# Google Geo code : Passing the values as argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, geolocation, geocoding

I am trying to locate the longitude and latitude of using Geocode in C# 
but i have error like :

public static List GetAddressesByKeyword(string keyword , string address = null)

```
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {  
            {"address", " 836 Kilbridge Lane, Coppell, TX" },
            {"input",keyword.Replace(" ", "+") },
            {"types", "geocode" },
            {"key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleApiKey"]}
        };

       if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address))
        parameters["address_components"] = String.Format("address{0}", address.ToLower());

        var queryString = String.Join("&", parameters.Select(kv => kv.Key + "=" + kv.Value));

        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?" + queryString );
```

Comment: have you checked what you are getting in queryString? It should be in correct format

Comment: yes, see the above code to access the address/... How can i access address parameters

Comment: can you share example url that you are calling? something like..  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=836KilbridgeLaneCoppell&types=geocode

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=211+LaTrobeStreet+Melbourne+Australia

Comment: i want http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=211+LaTrobeStreet+Melbourne+Australia api result but passsing address parameters in jason not directly like 211+latrobe+street

Comment: It is get api. you can not post json.

Comment: sorry i did not get you

Comment: Can You give possible way of this

Comment: This seems working good. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=211+LaTrobeStreet+Melbourne+Australia   -- this is giving proper response. Use this way only. What is issue in this way?

Comment: Yes, that's working but client required other way